# Initializing an instance with no use

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm a little bit confused why type instances are allowed to be created without their future use and the compiler doesn't emit even a warning about it.

```
public void M()
{
    new int();
    new object();
}
```

I've never created an instance without assigning it to a variable or calling it's members, and if I saw a line like `;new SomeType();` I would consider it as a mistype. I understand that technically .ctor can assign some static fields or do something else it's not supposed to do, but I don't consider it a sufficient argument for not emitting a warning.

Are there any patterns where ignoring an instance is appropriate? What am I missing?

Additional points not clear for me:
  1. *CodeAnalysis* gives a warning "CA1806: Do not ignore method results" for `object` but not for `int` or any other value type.
  2. The compiler doesn't emit IL for ignored structs even without optimization flag.

Comment: *I understand that technically .ctor can assign some static fields or do something else it's not supposed to do, but I don't consider it a sufficient argument for not emitting a warning.* - er... why? The constructor could do *anything*. That's a perfectly sufficient argument for not emitting a warning - compiler warnings don't exist to teach you good software engineering practices. Your entire question hangs on an arbitrary opinion.

Comment: The compiler never emits code for a call to a struct's default constructor, even when you assign it's result to a variable, because there is no code to emit. You can't define such a constructor either, and the reason is simple: they don't really exist at the IL level.

Comment: Your error is as Eric J points out, the supposition that one needs an argument for *not* implementing a feature. Features cost money and so have to be prioritized against all other possible features. The feature you suggest is a pretty good one, just not one that's ever made it to the top of the list. In particular, `new Exception();` really should be a warning: `warning, it looks like you forgot to type "throw"`.

Comment: As for your additional questions - and in the future please ask only one question per question posted - the "ignoring return value" is given for objects of reference type but not integers because `myString.ToUpper()` is always an error, but many many many methods return ints or bools or some such thing to indicate a condition that the user does not care about, or has access to via other means. For instance, the button clicked when a dialog is dismissed is both returned and stuck into a property, so ignoring the return value is common.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments, now i sorted my mess. My question was somewhat messy too because the main point wasn't about why warning is not emitted, but what is the purpose of this. I didn't consider it as a bug by default, vice-versa, I thought that I'm missing some feature of the framework/language. Now to me it's obvious that Code Analysis warning is fine. Sorry for the messy question, this is my first one on SO. In future I'll consider all the comments. I think it can be closed now :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiating an object can have side effects in C#.

The constructor could do almost anything, such as creating a database entry, writing a text file, or updating a static property somewhere before going out of scope.

Having said that, it is not good programming style to instantiate an object for the sole purpose of producing a side effect.  That is what the CodeAnalysis warning is implying.

> I understand that technically .ctor can assign some static fields or do something else it's not supposed to do, but I don't consider it a sufficient argument for not emitting a warning

As [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/about.aspx) said

> My usual response to “why is feature X not implemented?” is that of course all features are unimplemented until someone designs, implements, tests, documents and ships the feature, and no one has yet spent the money to do so. And yes, though I have famously pointed out that even small features can have large costs, this one really is dead easy, obviously correct, easy to test, and easy to document. Cost is always a factor of course, but the costs for this one really are quite small.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx